# Angular how to use ng-repeat with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

in ionic there is this demo

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
    {{playlist.title}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But I'm using using ioic-material and I want to repeat this

```
<a ng-repeat="shop in shops" href="#/app/shops" class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right"  > 
                <img ng-src="{{img}}">
                <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                <p>{{subtitle}}</p></a>
```

and here is the shops 
`$scope.shops = [
    { title: 'shop1', id: 1  , subtitle: 'Sport , Casual, Suits' , img: "img/material3.jpg.jpg"},
    { title: 'shop2', id: 2 , subtitle: 'Suits & Shoes, ' , img: "img/material3.jpg.jpg"},

  ];`
but the generated HTML I got.  (no errors)

```
<div class="list">

    <!-- ngRepeat: shop in shops --><a ng-repeat="shop in shops" href="#/app/shops" class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right">
                <img>
                <h2 class="ng-binding"></h2>
                <p class="ng-binding"></p>
                </a><!-- end ngRepeat: shop in shops --><a ng-repeat="shop in shops" href="#/app/shops" class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right">
                <img>
                <h2 class="ng-binding"></h2>
                <p class="ng-binding"></p>
                </a><!-- end ngRepeat: shop in shops -->
        </div>
```

So what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Show initialization of your `$scope.shops` because it seems like there are no shops.

Comment: thaks for help  @skubski

Answer (score 2):

got it I should do :

```
<a ng-repeat="shop in shops" href="#/app/shops" class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right"  >
                <img ng-src="{{shop.img}}">
                <h2>{{shop.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{shop.subtitle}}</p>
                </a>
```

instead of

```
<a ng-repeat="shop in shops" href="#/app/shops" class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right"  > 
            <img ng-src="{{img}}">
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <p>{{subtitle}}</p></a>
```